# Keeping ASP.NET Webforms templates DRY

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dry

I've inherited an ASP.NET Webforms applications that deals with numerous similar views of data.  However, because of the  templates and because it uses the  control which also has separate templates for various modes (EditItemTemplate, ItemTemplate, etc.) I have several pages that have numerous repetitive definitions of how to display each piece of data.

EDIT:  For clarity, the duplications are of small chunks of the overall UI, not duplication of the entire UI.  A column definition in a subtable of a grid inside a formview can get repeated 4 or more  times (Both the ItemTemplate and the EditItem Template of the FormView would have both ItemTemplates and EditItemTemplates for the particular master table volumn.)

(Needles to say this makes making and verifying changes drastically harder than it should be.)

If this was XAML, I could declare the repetitive parts as Resources and reuse them to achieve a level of DRYness. (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself)

I've made some code snippets for adding new items to keep additions consistent, but it doesn't help with making sure edits happen everywhere consistently.

Are there any tools to help with this in ASP.NET Webforms or am I stuck with WET code?  (Actually, **W**rite **E**verything **T**wice is a understatement for this situation.  Some pages have up to 8 repetitions of the same UI for columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exact same UI, then I would question why you need multiple controls in the first place.

If they truly are that identical, then why not consolidate the controls into a single control and use Object oriented techniques to alter the code implementation that uses the single control in the code behind.

For example, you might have a dictionary of Action delegates that all use the same UI based on parameters a different implementation gets selected.  If you do this correctly (say, using an MVP pattern) then you can make this highly testable and create unit tests to test your different implementations.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.   I have edited the question for clarity.